# Why is the input not split at start of input when regex is blank

Tags: java, regex, split

I found a neat way to extract all characters (as Strings) of a string:

```
String[] chars = "abc".split(""); // "a", "b", "c"
```

I expected to get a blank first term, but to my surprise it *didn't* split at start of input, even though a blank matches at start of input - ie between `^` and `"a"`.

Conversely, a non-blank regex *does* match at start:

```
String[] chars = ";a;b;c".split(";"); // "", "a", "b", "c"
```

**Why does a blank regex *not* split (ie match) at start of input?**

Comment: I have added an answer to the other question. The other question quoted the wrong part of the code.